# Need for WCF Services

Tags: .net, wcf

I am just getting started on WCF. Earlier was working in web services. As far as I know a web service can be consumed in a platform independent way. Is that the case with WCF services also? Or WCF services are specific to just .net applications? When should I consider designing WCF Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF was designed and built to be extremely interoperable! It supports the WS-* specifications, it can talk to anything from Java to Python to Ruby to whatever you can dream of...

WCF is the new standard for designing and building service oriented applications - anything from classic web services to more advanced corporate services. WCF is much more flexible and powerful than the "old-style" ASP.NET/ASMX web service in that is supports a ton of protocols (not just HTTP, but also TCP/IP, MSMQ and a lot more).

WCF is the technology to supercede not just ASMX webservices, but also .NET remoting and others. It offers a unified and simple, configuration-driven approach to building services.

**YES!** you should **definitely** have a very good look at WCF if you need to build services anytime now.

As for resoures: there's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, check out the [screen cast library up on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx) for some really useful, 10-15 minute chunks of information on just about any topic related to WCF you might be interested in.

There's also a bunch of video resources for WCF - my favorites are:

- DotNet Rocks TV Show #122: [Miguel Castro on Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122)
- DotNet Rocks TV Show #135: [Keith Elder Demystifies WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135)

Comment: So what I directly get from your answer is that when I decide creating services from now, I should stick to WCF instead of asmx, as WCF is the new standard for building services. Am I correct?

Comment: @SARAVAN: **yes!** WCF is today's and tomorrow's technology for doing any kind of service-oriented applications.

Answer (score 1):

When we start looking at WCF we make the mistake that WCF is the parallel of standard ASMX Web services. This is simply not the case. WCF is an umbrella technology which encompasses several features; Web services are just one part of it.

The advantage they provide is that with the use of WCF your architecture remains the same be it web services, remoting, msmq etc. Meaning the underlying plumbing can be easily changed. You don't need to worry about where you're getting the data, from across the network or across a process in your computer. You code will still look the same.

This gives great stability to developers. The focus comes into configuration files and WCF is all about configuration files. You can tweak it to your hearts content and make this thing truly flexible.

Comment: Yes I do agree after looking in to a few samples. Thanks for your answer.